# Interacting with the current user object in firebase requires me the type user.user, why must I type user twice?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a registration  page for users to register on a firebase database in a web page(it's wordpress).

For example when I create the user and then try a simple console log to check the created user's uid like so:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function(user){
                console.log(user.uid);
            });
```

I get an "undefined". But when I attempt to do the same thing by typing

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function(user){
                console.log(user.user.uid);
            });
```

It works correctly.

Why is this?

I followed the documentation for initialising firebase and then set the reference to the auth as

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
```

Thanks for any help. I am new to both Javascript and Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)

> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) returns firebase.Promise containing non-null firebase.auth.UserCredential

Clicking [`firebase.auth.UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) shows you it has the structure

```
{
  user: nullable firebase.User,
  credential: nullable firebase.auth.AuthCredential,
  operationType: (nullable string or undefined),
  additionalUserInfo: (nullable firebase.auth.AdditionalUserInfo or undefined)
}
```

So you are accessing the `user` property of the returned `UserCredential` object which you have named `user`.

If you wanted to, you could change `user` to `userCredential` to help clarify what it is and avoid future confusion.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(userCredential){
  console.log(userCredential.user.uid);
});
```